# I couldn't install extension anymore using Magento Connect Manager

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-connect-manager

I couldn't install extension anymore using **Magento Connect Manager**. I can login to Magento Connect Manager, but every step that I did, it always show the login form again even if I tried to enter the correct login account, the connect manager never installed my extension. The re-enter password always loop when I'm trying to do something in the Magento Connect Manager.

Could someone help me to fixed this weird thing?

***SOLVED***

now i have another problem but this time when i install a new template, Show this

[image]

I've tried this but nothing happen,

> find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} \;
>
> find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} \;
>
> chmod u+x bin/magento

Comment: Disable Your Extension One by One and Then Check.

Answer (score 0):

[It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/)

in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security. but i tested many extensions, i did't faced any security problems....

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `.htaccess` file with default `.htaccess` file and then try to install. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with the cookie domain.

My advise is: make sure every `base_url` is set up correct (check the database).
Clear the whole Magento cache (folder: `var/cache/`).
There is also a `cache.cfg` inside the downloader directory, please try to delete this one as well.

Afterwards delete all the cookies that might be related to the new domain. Then try to login again.

Also I'd suggest you to use the mage script via SSH:

```
cd /path/to/magento
chmod +x ./mage
./mage mage-setup
./mage install community VendorPrefix_PackageName
```

E.g.: `./mage install community Thebod_Shippingrates` or something similar.

check the base_url settings. But for me, I also had to put the domain in  *System > Configuration > General > Web > Session Cookie Management > Cookie Domain*.

Many features of Magento will work with this field empty, but I had to put my domain in that field to get Magento Connect Manager to not do a login loop.

Clear your browser cache & cookies , and Magento Clear Session as well cache

Also try reverting any changes u made in `.htaccess` as well

Comment: Can you please mark it as answer as it solved your your problem